# Group by SQL not grouping

Tags: sql

I have this query that works fine, except that it brings 2 records.  It can make the grouping. I have 2 different customers (CUSTMANE) -- it looks this is why, and that's why I added the case.

Any thoughts on how to group so I can get the sum?

```
SELECT 

sum (INVOICEAMOUNT) as INVOICEAMOUNT ,
sum (PROFIT) as PROFIT,

ITEM,
ITEMNAME,
DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 6,  DATE), 6 + 7) as [Week],

case CUSTNAME
 when (select CUSTNAME where CUSTNAME like ('B%')) then 'Cust B'
 when (select CUSTNAME where CUSTNAME like ('H%')) then 'Cust H'
end as CUSTNAME,

case ITEMGROUP
 when (select ITEMGROUP where ITEMGROUP in ('CEM','SPECIAL')) then 'C & S'
 when (select ITEMGROUP where ITEMGROUP in ('CMH','CMG')) then 'C & C'
end as ITEMGROUP

FROM EXTRACT
 where DATE > = DATEADD(week,-5,GETDATE())
 and ID in ('230') 
 group by  

ITEM,
ITEMNAME,
CUSTNAME,
ITEMGROUP,
DATE
```

Comment: Please post some sample data, received output and desired output.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You don't seem to understand the order in which statements are executed.

Comment: Selecting one thing and grouping by another might be causing your unexpected results.  Look at week vs date.

Comment: I'd imagine the group by is grouping on the original values not the new ones in the case statement.

Comment: grouping by date is what's causing the issue, you're not needing it since youre doing date math.  you need to group by the result of your date add [week] not date.

Comment: this is the result i get:

INVOICEAMOUNT PROFIT   ITEM  ITEMNAME CUSTNAME ITEMGROUP Week
6006       3634.96  1003  PRODUCTA CUST B    C & S 12/1/13
60060        34255.2 1003  PRODUCTA CUST B C & S 12/1/13

this is what i would like to get 

INVOICEAMOUNT PROFIT   ITEM ITEMNAME CUSTNAME ITEMGROUP Week
66066       37890.16 1003 PRODUCTA CUST B C & S 12/1/13

one line with the sum of invoice and profit

Comment: i need the date, i need to know the fist day of the week

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  SUM(INVOICEAMOUNT) AS INVOICEAMOUNT
      , SUM(PROFIT) AS PROFIT
      , ITEM
      , ITEMNAME
      , DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 6, DATE), 6 + 7) AS [Week]
      , CASE WHEN CUSTNAME LIKE 'B%' THEN 'Cust B'
             WHEN CUSTNAME LIKE 'H%' THEN 'Cust H'
        END AS CUSTNAME
      , CASE WHEN ITEMGROUP IN ( 'CEM', 'SPECIAL' ) THEN 'C & S'
             WHEN ITEMGROUP IN ( 'CMH', 'CMG' ) THEN 'C & C'
        END AS ITEMGROUP
FROM    EXTRACT
WHERE   DATE > = DATEADD(week, -5, GETDATE())
        AND ID IN ( '230' )
GROUP BY ITEM
      , ITEMNAME
      , CASE WHEN CUSTNAME LIKE 'B%' THEN 'Cust B'
             WHEN CUSTNAME LIKE 'H%' THEN 'Cust H'
        END
      , CASE WHEN ITEMGROUP IN ( 'CEM', 'SPECIAL' ) THEN 'C & S'
             WHEN ITEMGROUP IN ( 'CMH', 'CMG' ) THEN 'C & C'
        END
      , DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 6, DATE), 6 + 7)
```

Comment: this is the result i get:

INVOICEAMOUNT PROFIT   ITEM  ITEMNAME CUSTNAME ITEMGROUP Week
6006       3634.96  1003  PRODUCTA CUST B    C & S 12/1/13
60060        34255.2 1003  PRODUCTA CUST B C & S 12/1/13

this is what i would like to get 

INVOICEAMOUNT PROFIT   ITEM ITEMNAME CUSTNAME ITEMGROUP Week
66066       37890.16 1003 PRODUCTA CUST B C & S 12/1/13

Comment: Wonder if you have a data cleansing issue. do you have a space in your customer ids or names?

Comment: just looked at that, they are the same, also that is why added the case, so i can name them the same

Comment: But you don't have a CASE for item or item name. that's the only two columns that can be causing your split.

Comment: sorry i meant the CUSTNAME and ITEMGROUP, and the names are the same ... i just ran the query without the CASE on the CUSTNAME and it is working, i get one line ... i know it its the CUSTNAME, but why is it not grouping ...

Comment: Sorry, I went back and looked at your SQL, and made a modification; see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Stuart, it is working now, Thank you so much!! i see what you did, is it not good to have the SELECT in the CASE.
Thank you again